# How do my A records have to look like - are these correct?

Tags: domains, dns-servers

I'm using some fictional IP addresses here, but the problem is real.

My default A Record:

```
* # this is for anysubdomain.example.com, I suppose
@ # and this is for example.com
www # this is for www.example.com
```

There are also these entries. What do they do in this context? My MX records are elsewhere.

```
mail
webmail
pop
smtp
```

Now I'd like to point to my own server. Let's say that my IP is `1.2.3.4` I would then 
write:

```
* 1.2.3.4
@ 1.2.3.4
www 1.2.3.4
```

Is that correct? I read something about `* IN A 1.2.3.4` - what's that notation?

Assuming my application runs on `1.2.3.4:80`, everything should be fine, right? I am new to the A records concept and I'd like to ask before changing and deconstructing my system.

Comment: [Example IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3151552/209139).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want your root domain (aka `example.com`) to resolve to `1.2.3.4`. In this case, all what you have to do is to create an A record that points to that IP

```
example.com A 1.2.3.4
```

depending on your DNS hosting interface, you may either need to leave the record name empty (to match `example.com`) or other providers asks you to reference it with `@`. In that case

```
@ A 1.2.3.4
```

If then you also what the `www` hostname (aka `www.example.com`) to map to the same server, you can either add another A record

```
www A 1.2.3.4
# or depending on your DNS hosting interface
www.example.com A 1.2.3.4
```

or a CNAME to the root domain

```
www CNAME example.com
# or depending on your DNS hosting interface
www CNAME @
```

The wildcard records `*.example.com` allows you to map any subdomain of a specific level to a server. For instance

```
*.example.com A 1.2.3.4
```

will map any one-level subdomain of example.com (including `www.example.com` but not `example.com` root domain) to that IP. It also works with a CNAME

```
*.example.com CNAME example.com
```

You should avoid wildcards unless you really need it, for instance for a subdomain-based multi-tenant application

Note. In my examples I always use the format

```
DNS NAME - RECORD TYPE - CONTENT
```

but how you create those records and the order of the items depends on your DNS hosting provider interface.